# RealmSwift 10.7.2 with xCode 12.4 compiler and build errors

Tags: ios, swift, realm, xcode12

I have upgraded my xCode to the latest version 12.4 and upgraded my RealmSwift to 10.7.2 using cocoapods.

But now I get a lot of compiler errors and can't build my project anymore.
Errors like:

- Cannot find type 'RealmApp' in scope
- Cannot find type 'SyncUser' in scope
- Cannot find type 'AppCredentials' in scope
- etc...

I tried to downgrade RealmSwift to 10.1.4 like in the example at the mongoDB documentation, but the problem is still there.

I couldn't find any information if xCode 12.4 is compatible with the latest RealmSwift version.

Could anybody find a solution for this problem, or should I downgrade xCode back to version 11.x?
Or are there any Project or Target settings I could try?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `RealmApp`, `SyncUser`, `AppCredentials`, etc have been renamed in the new API. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000-beta3-release-notes-2020-08-17

Comment: Are you saying you upgraded from Realm 5.3.2 to Realm 10.7.2? The changes @KentaroOkuda linked happened 6 months ago.